# IISRESET Error

Tags: iis, iis-7, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I received the following error while running IISRESET on our MOSS 2007 Index Server:

*Restart attempt failed.

The data is invalid. (2147942413, 8007000d)*

It appears that the IIS Admin Service is failing to stop properly and thus cannot be restarted.

The server is running Windows Server 2008 x64.

Answer (score 1):

Something is messed with IIS when that occurs.  I've run into this sometimes when making manual customizations to applicationHost.config and having a typo.

If it's a config issue, a trick that can work is to open up IIS Manager and navigate around a bit.  IIS Manager will actually work if IIS is down, and if there is a syntax error, it will give you a fairly specific error message on what the issue is.

It can also occur if your applicationHost.config is referencing a module that isn't installed on that server.  If that's the case, the best solution is to uninstall what you just installed, or manually pull up parts of the config until you narrow down what caused it.

Alternately, try reverting back to a previous backup of IIS to confirm that it's a .config issue.  Also, check out Event Viewer.  It should give more clues.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen this a couple of times.  Do you think there could be a timing issue with the configuration somehow?  Reason I ask, we use the System.Web.Administration Object Model to create/delete App Pools and Sites for deployment.  After doing so, we'll issue a iisreset.exe for good measure.

Sporadically, iisreset will give us the *data is invalid* message Alex has seen.  By the time a support person gets on the box to investigate, the issue can't be repeated because iisreset will magically start working.  The last time this happen, iisreset.exe ran 23 seconds after we finished up with the App Pool and Site creation.  So I would expect a synch issue to be resolved by then, but maybe not?

I haven't used AppCMD for a while, but I remember some issues where when using AppCMD, I would get sporadic false configuration errors when trying to start an AppPool after creating it.  In that case I put in some sleep time to make sure the config is synced.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've also seen this error message when the World Wide Web Publishing service is stopped. With the exact same "error code" or "error numbers" or whatever you'd call them.